# Can't get only first level li from nested ul li

Tags: jquery, css, animation, accordion

I have this on jsfiddle, [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/sBssF/6/)

How would I have this to only click on class 'accordion' and toggle?
It's currently toggling when clicking the nested li(testsubmenu) also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.accordion>a').click(function() {
    $('#nav > li:not(.accordion)').slideToggle();
    $('.subnav li').fadeToggle();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/sBssF/21/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `$('.subnav li').bind("click",function(){ return false;});`

[The code](http://jsfiddle.net/2gHCw/)

```
 $('.accordion:not(.accordion li)').click(function() {
        $('#nav > li:not(.accordion)').slideToggle();
        $('.subnav li').fadeToggle();
    });
 $('.subnav li').bind("click",function(){ return false;});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this works also, but the other solution seems more simple.

Answer (score 1):

Do the action only if the actual `a` link is clicked, not the whole `li`

```
$('.accordion:not(.accordion li) > a').click(function() {
    $('#nav > li:not(.accordion)').slideToggle();
    $('.subnav li').fadeToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sBssF/6/

Comment: Thank you for such fast response!